# Sparql: string after last

Tags: sparql

Assuming I have some triples like this

```
:a ex:fileName "abc.txt".
:b ex:fileName "another.file.doc".
```

and assuming I want to create a SPARQL query that returns me the filename without a file extension? Like

```
"abc"
"another.file"
```

Does SPARQL have an easy way of doing something like "substring before last" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`REPLACE()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-replace) with a matching regexp:

```
SELECT ?file ?filename
WHERE {
  ?file ex:fileName ?rawFilename .

  BIND( REPLACE( ?rawFilename , '\\.[^.]*$', '' ) AS ?filename )
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks. I am assuming that there are no "plain" functions to do this.

Comment: No, all String functions can be found here: https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-strings  Everything beyond has to be covered by REGEX + a chain of those functions - if possible indeed.